# How to create a SlotOfQImage in QT Rust?

Tags: qt, rust, qimage, slot, qtwidgets

I'm trying to define a custom QT Slot/Signal for passing a `QImage`.

I'm using `qt_widgets` crate which has many predefined slot types like `SlotOfQIcon`. However it doesn't have one for QImage. I've looked at the source code which is generated with this tool: https://github.com/rust-qt/ritual.

Is it possible to do this in regular Rust project without running complex multistage build involving code generation?

List of implemented slots for reference:

https://docs.rs/qt_widgets/0.3.0/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/qt_widgets/

I've tried to copy paste generated code for other widgets and modify it, but it doesn't look like a right approach. I don't want to regenerate the whole library just for this case. Are there any simpler options?